# How update Sails.js to newest version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, sails.js

How can I update my Sails.js framework (installed on OSX) to newest version using terminal/command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
npm update [-g] [<name> [<name> ...]]
```

This command will update all the packages listed to the latest version (specified by the tag config). It will also install missing packages.

If the `-g` flag is specified, this command will update globally installed packages.

So for you, I guess that would be: `npm update sails` or `sudo npm -g update sails` depending on how and where you installed it.

Answer (score 17):

To update to the latest stable version:

```
npm update sails
```

or, if you've installed it globally, it would be:

```
sudo npm update -g sails
```

to install globally.  This will overwrite any existing install.

Comment: When the full version 0.10 will be released? Would like to update my sails version to 0.10.0